# mapping image to the image button in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How will I retrieve  an image fron the database I am not using a path I am using a byte format to store the image.

```
byte[] image = (byte[])dr[11];
string imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(image);
```

how will I map this image to an image button?. How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to convert the image format to byte array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21473382/how-to-convert-the-image-format-to-byte-array)

Comment: How this one is different from one you've asked 20 minutes ago? Please also check this [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) post for recommendation on thank you notes.

Comment: Duplicate of the following.
Try to following link. It might be helpful for you. [How to retrieve binary image from database using C# in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998763/how-to-retrieve-binary-image-from-database-using-c-sharp-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the following URL's

we need to create the Handler and map it to the Image button

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETFuturesGeneratingDynamicImagesWithHttpHandlersGetsEasier.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I did this in my project to display image (saved in database as varbinary(MAX)) in Picture box, Here is the code

`photo_aray = (byte[])drow[14];
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(photo_aray);
 pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);`

May be you can mold this as your requirement