# Error is" string or binary data truncated"

Tags: c#, sql-server

If txt file is uploaded then is successfullly. But large txt file is uploaded then error occurs. ***Error is" string or binary data truncated"***

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~\\upload\\") + FileUpload1.FileName);
        f = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);
        st = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
        ml = Server.MapPath("~\\upload\\");
        nww = FileUpload1.FileName;
        ty = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);
        kk = ml + f + ty;

        FileInfo fz = new FileInfo(kk);
        long s1 = fz.Length;
        string fsize = s1.ToString();

        string dat = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(kk, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fs.Length);
        fs.Close();
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("insert into ofileup     (Fid,filename,files,ftype,fsize,filepath,oname,status,date) values(@Fid,@filename,@files,@ftype,@fsize,@filepath,@oname,@status,@date)", con);

        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fid", Label14.Text);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filename", st);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@files", buffer);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ftype", ty);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fsize", fsize);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filepath", kk);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oname", Label16.Text);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status","waiting");
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", dat);

        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        Label17.Text = "File Uploaded Successfully...";
        autoid();
    }
```

In database

- Fid        int
- filename   varchar(250)
- files      varchar(150)
- ftype      varchar(150)
- fsize      bigint
- filepath   varchar(150)
- oname      varchar(50)
- status     varchar(50)
- date       varchar(50)

Comment: Well use, your `files` field says it can only handle 150 characters, but you're populating it with the contents of a file which presumably is larger than that. (You're also not reading it very cleanly, and reading it as binary data despite the field being a text field, but those are separate problems.) How do you expect the database to handle a large file when your schema doesn't allow it?

Comment: Though this issue is related to Database.
Here are some point to support your .net application to allow a large file upload. `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097152" executionTimeout="600" />` Just set in web.config under `<system.web>` section. In the example I am setting the maximum length that is 2GB. Please note that the `maxRequestLength` is set in KB's and it can be set up to `2GB` (2079152 KB's). But default file size limit is (`4M`B).

Answer (score 1):

In the database, if you're storing a file in a record - you need to change your `files` column to `nvarchar(max)` (or `ntext` for previous SQL servers, both work).     In reality, though, if you're storing pure bytes, using `varbinary` is the best choice for you (unless it's over 250k or so, then use `FILESTREAM` set up instead, if you can).

Essentially, you're only allowing the file to be 150 characters in byte size - total, by restricting `files` to `varchar(150)`.

The error message is SQL server telling you that you're trying to put more characters into a SQL column than it allows - it ran out of room, and the data would be truncated/chopped-off if it let it continue. Instead, it errors out.

In short, increase the size of your `file` column, to `varchar/nvarchar (max)` or `varbinary(max)` and consider using `FILESTREAM` if you plan on storing files > 250k.

Comment: if (e.CommandName == "Select")
        {
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[x];
            string fid = row.Cells[0].Text;
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select oname,files,filename from ofileup where Fid=@Fid", con);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fid", fid);
            SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();

Comment: if (dr.Read())
            {
                Response.Clear();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                //Response.ContentType = dr["ftype"].ToString();
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "files;filename=" + dr["filename"].ToString());     // to open file prompt Box open or Save file         
                Response.Charset = "";
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
               Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dr["files"]);
                Response.End();
            }
            con.Close();  
        }

Comment: In the above code Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dr["files"]);  is show error.The error is unable to cast system.string to system.binary

Comment: That's next to impossible to read -- but it appears by looking at the error you're receiving is that you're setting the content type of the response to a string variant (like a CSV?) -- and trying to .BinaryWrite to it.   Look here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998763/how-to-retrieve-binary-image-from-database-using-c-sharp-in-asp-net and also just google for "how to stream a file from a database in C#" - you'll get a million hits (give or take 5).