# How to retrieve image from database to picturebox using ImageConverter?

Tags: c#, database, picturebox

```
Image img = PictureBox1.Image;
byte[] arr;
ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
arr = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tblWerknemers2 (Naam,Voornaam,Foto) values(@Naam,@Voornaam@Foto)", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Naam", txtNaam.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Voornaam", txtVoornaam.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Foto", arr);
```

Here I insert the image into the database but the problem is that I don't know how to retrieve it. Here below is how I tried to do it.

```
SqlDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader();

while (read.Read())
{
    txtNaam.Text = (read["Naam"].ToString());
    txtVoornaam.Text = (read["Voornaam"].ToString());  
    arr = (byte[])read["Foto"];              
}
read.Close();
```

Comment: Here is one way on how you do it: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=read%20image%20from%20database%20c%23

Comment: But here is a possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998763/how-to-retrieve-binary-image-from-database-using-c-sharp-in-asp-net

Comment: still can't figure out how :/

Comment: It is okay, just wait and someone will definitely post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
byte[] arr = (byte[])read["Foto"];
if (arr.Length > 0)
{
    MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(arr);
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(mem);
}
```