# how to add button click event in grid view in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

1)
I had a GridView and I added a button in every row. I want to know how to select one row by clicking that button according to that row. And I should insert that record into an other table.

Eg:- I have two tables (Course and Wish List)
I bind the course details into the GridView and add a button as "ADD TO WISHLIST" at last column. 
I want to add that record into the wishlist table clicking the button.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2wyB.jpg)

2)
My second need is: I have added an image in a database table as binary value successfully. But now I can't load this data. How can I do that?

Comment: You need to learn about RowCommand event of. GridView. Follow https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Second point: Entity Framework: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25400555/save-and-retrieve-image-binary-from-sql-server-using-entity-framework-6 
or https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b818de10-9dbb-4ca4-9c31-8f3305713eee/how-to-save-and-get-files-in-database-with-cnet?forum=Vsexpressvcs or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998763/how-to-retrieve-binary-image-from-database-using-c-sharp-in-asp-net