# How to retrieve Image from database to gridview in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

I just want to store and retrive image from database to gridview . After the image is store i want to display the stored image in a grid view. How to do?

> retrieve Image from database to gridview in asp.net

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                BindGridView();
            }

        }
        private void BindGridView()
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Student", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);

            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve binary image from database using C# in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998763/how-to-retrieve-binary-image-from-database-using-c-sharp-in-asp-net)

Comment: Your suggested link wouldn't give solution or clarification to my probelm. could you tell me how to solve my issue.@VDWWD

Comment: @VDWWD has provided how to extract a binary image from the database, you need to create the image object and put the source as per his message.  It wont auto do that for you

Comment: This could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132451/how-to-display-binary-images-into-a-gridview-in-asp-net-using-c

Comment: It has a solution. The accepted answer turns the image into a base64 and sets it as the source for an Image Control.