# How to view byte image in a gridview in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to view the image in gridview from dataBase. In dataBase the image is in byte formate. How to retrieve and view that images in grid View. I don't know how to code for this.Anyone know help me to solve the issue.

> To display image in gridview from database.the image is in byte
>   format.How to view that bytecode as image in gridview

Here is my code:

```
//Image Upload Code Here//
protected void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            Label2.Visible = true;
            Label2.Text = "Please Select Image File";    //checking if file uploader has no file selected
        }
        else
        {
            int length = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
            byte[] pic = new byte[length];


            FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(pic, 0, length);
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            //   SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("insert into Student" + "(RegNo,Name,DOB,Gender,Address,Country,Picture) values(@RegNo,@Name,@DOB,@Gender,@Address,@Country,@photo)", con);
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("sp", con);
            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  
            con.Open();
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegNo", RegNo.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", Dob.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", Gender.SelectedValue);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", Address.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", Country.Text);
            //cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datetime", DateTime.Now);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Picture", pic);

        try
            {
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Label2.Visible = true;
                Label2.Text = "Image Uploaded Sucessfully";
                con.Close();//after Sucessfully uploaded image
            }
        catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

    Response.Redirect("~/WebForm1.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve binary image from database using C# in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998763/how-to-retrieve-binary-image-from-database-using-c-sharp-in-asp-net)

Comment: Are you perhaps using 2 accounts?? Because this other question is rather similar and has almost the same username... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48639810/how-to-retrieve-image-from-database-to-gridview-in-asp-net. And as my and other comments explained, the solution is in the duplicate (again)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is no event with name ItemdataBound for gridview. For gridview use RowDataBound event instead. Below is the sample implementation for the same.

ASPX:

```
  <asp:GridView runat="server"  ID="grd" OnRowDataBound ="grd_RowDataBound"  >
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="image">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                          <img src='<%# Eval("imagedata") %>' id="imageControl" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>   
                    </asp:TemplateField> 
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

CS:

```
protected void grd_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Row.RowType==DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage imageControl = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage)e.Row.FindControl("imageControl");
            if (((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["imagedata"] != DBNull.Value)
            {
                imageControl.Src = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])(((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem))["imagedata"]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ItemDataBound event of grid view as given below:

```
if(e.Item.ItemType ==ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
  System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage imageControl =(System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage) e.Item.FindControl("imageControl");
            if (((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem)["imagedata"] != DBNull.Value)
            {
                imageControl.Src = "data:image/png;base64,"+ Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem)["imagedata"]) ;
            }
}
```

First find the image control inside your grive view and set it's image source property to "data:image/png;base64,"+ Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem)["imagedata"]) ;

Note: imagedata should be the name of column you used to save image.

Comment: How to use ItemdataBound.Really i don't know how to use. Am new in Asp.net